# Error during font loading with pdfjslib in VUE

Tags: pdf, vuejs2, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

Hi I have an error when loading a pdf in my project (pdf viewer). I have a pdf with a font that is actually normal and I get this error

*`Warning: Error during font loading: The CMap "baseUrl" parameter must be specified, ensure that the "cMapUrl" and "cMapPacked" API parameters are provided.`*

This is how I load the library

```
let pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js');
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = require('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry');
```

this is the original pdf
[image]

And the display does not show the font

Answer (score 0):

The PDF.js includes normal PDF fonts, make sure your server serve the `web/cmaps` directory correctly.

You can open the developer console, there should be a 404 network request, make sure your server host `cmaps` directory in right path.